# How can i opptimize that code of asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to optimize that code that is written bellow if you have an answer please quickly reply me, In This code I want to put different conditions and return a different url in each condition if it is possible with optimize way then reply me:

```
if (Offer1_Rb_Yes.Checked == true || DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        int offerid = MyOffers[0].OfferId;
        DAL.offers Offer = new DAL.offers();
        Offer = obj.GetOffer(offerid);
        if (Offer.CampId == "WINE-MAKERS-CHOICE")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "WINE-MAKERS-CHOICE&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&c1=" + Gender;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "LETS-INSURE-CA")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "LETS-INSURE-CA&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&c1=" + Age;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "SOLAR-BROKER")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "SOLAR-BROKER&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&c1=" + Age;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "WENATEX-AU")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "WENATEX-AU&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&street1=" + street1 + "&towncity=" + suburb + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&source=" + Source;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "MODERN-SOLAR-COMP")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "MODERN-SOLAR-COMP&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&street1=" + street1 + "&towncity=" + suburb + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&phone2=" + Phone2 + "&gender=" + Gender + "&solar_pv=" + Solar_pv;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "CAREERS-AUSTRALIA-3")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "CAREERS-AUSTRALIA-3&sid=TPF34" + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "GOOD-LIFE")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "GOOD-LIFE&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "GRYPHON-SOLAR")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "GRYPHON-SOLAR&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&county=VIC&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&source=" + Source + "&age=" + Age;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "GRYPHON-SOLAR-WA")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "GRYPHON-SOLAR-WA&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&county=WA&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&source=" + Source + "&age=" + Age;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "ACQUIRE-LEARNING")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "ACQUIRE-LEARNING&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&industry=" + Industry;
        }
        else if (Offer.CampId == "KOGAN")
        {
            url1 = url1 + "KOGAN&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&towncity=" + suburb + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&ipaddress=" + ipaddress;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well you need to post this question **[here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it as below:

```
if (offer5_Rb_Yes.Checked == true)
{
    int offerid = MyOffers[4].OfferId;
    DAL.offers Offer = new DAL.offers();
    Offer = obj.GetOffer(offerid);
    url5=url5+Offer.CampId+"&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&c1=" + Age;
    return url5;
}
```

I see that only thing gets changed in your url is `Offer.CampId` and rest remains same! so you can do it as above!

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that in the first condition your `url` has small change at the end! Not sure whether its intentional or by mistake! If it's intentional then you may try using `ternary operators` as your `url` changes only for one condition and remains same for other 2.

```
url5= Offer.CampId=="WINE-MAKERS-CHOICE"?
      url5+Offer.CampId+"&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&c1=" + Gender
      :url5+Offer.CampId+"&sid=TPF34" + "&email=" + Email + "&firstname=" + FirstName + "&lastname=" + LastName + "&dob=" + DOB + "&county=" + State + "&postcode=" + PostCode + "&phone1=" + Phone1 + "&c1=" + Age;
```

Comment: Thanks Your suggestion is very good but i have 11 type url and parameters of url are always change, In the above code i mention only three type url

Comment: In this case I suggest you to use `switch` statement which is more efficient!!

Comment: Yes it is more efficient than if-else. Thanks for giving suggestion to me Rao Sir

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: One more thing Now I have more then one url like url1,url2,url3 etc and i want to pass these urls to the webReqest.create method,It can be possible or not